# Buscar no MySQL com FULLTEXT IN BOOLEAN MODE inclusive os operadores da keyword?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, algoritmo-de-busca

Como fazer para que no BD MySQL, em uma tabela InnoDB com dois campos indexados por FULLTEXT, seja executada uma busca através da query MATCH (column1, column2) AGAINST('keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE) incluindo inclusive os operadores que estão na palavra a ser pesquisada?

Entenda:

```
SELECT * FROM languages WHERE MATCH (title, body) AGAINST ('C++' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Lembrando que o sinal de `+` é um dos operadores que podem ser utilizados na palavra a ser pesquisada IN BOOLEAN MODE, como `-`, `<`, `>`, `@`, entre outros para obter resultados mais estendidos.

Assim sendo, a query do nosso exemplo acima falha, devido a palavra ser **C++**, que na verdade é interpretada como sendo uma letra seguida de dois operadores (C`++`).

Gostaria que a busca ignorasse os operadores mas que realizasse a pesquisa com eles IN BOOLEAN MODE, não pode ser IN NATURAL LANGUAGE, a não ser que o modo de linguagem natural consiga trazer inclusive os 50% que são descartados da busca, ou seja, trazer o resultado com todos os valores existentes como no modo booleano, sem ignorar as palavras que são muito repetitivas.

Para completar a informação e quem sabe elucidar outros novos caminhos para resolução da questão, a linguagem de programação que implementará o processo de pesquisa será PHP e a palavra que deverá ser pesquisada será carregada em uma variável via POST (AJAX) após o preenchimento do campo de busca pelo usuário. Qualquer outro caminho que leve ao mesmo resultado também é bem vindo!

Comment: Ingrid, entendo que é chato as vezes fazer uma pergunta e não obter respostas(eu tenho algumas assim também), mas evite adicionar comentarios off-topic no corpo da pergunta. Veja como uma oportunidade de melhorar sua pergunta, releia, veja se você mesma consegue entender claramente o texto, e se tiver certeza que está tudo bem, só resta aguardar. As vezes não é a pergunta que está ruim, é porque ninguém que domine o assunto dela possa ter a visto ainda. No mais, paciencia, uma hora alguem te responde :)

Comment: @DiegoF obrigada por me ajudar! Fez bem de remover minha última edição na pergunta, eu sou realmente muito ansiosa pela resposta =)